# How to create a custom button in android xml

Tags: android, xml, button

I am look for the right way to create this kind of custom buttons in android (xml).[image]

I know i can set this image as a background for a button, but i am look for a way to re-create it with xml to make it be responsive for various screen sizes.

Comment: I think you will have solution for this at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483060/android-responsive-image-button-layout)

Comment: That was not what i was looking for, what i'm attamping to have is that exact design written in xml. Thanks for the reply anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a layer-list to achieve that design using XML.
Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:left="60dp">
    <shape>
        <size
            android:width="200dp"
            android:height="120dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#474946"
            android:endColor="#181818"
            android:angle="270"/>
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="2dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="140dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="120dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

You can also use a 9-patch for that.

Comment: thank you for this code i'll give it a try. But i'm just curious if a 9 patch image would behave in the right way when stretched ?